# How to use the comparison test to show that this series diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series:
$\displaystyle\sum_{m=2}^\infty \left( \displaystyle\frac{5}{7 \, m + 28} \right)$

The partial sums are obviously smaller than the harmonic series, but that doesn't allow me to conclude that the series diverges.

What must I compare the series to?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski It works! Thanks. You should include it as an answer.

Comment: You can also use the direct comparison test, by noting that for all $m \geq 2$, the inequality $7m + 28 \leq 21m$ holds, and therefore $$\frac{5}{7m + 28} \geq \frac{5}{21m}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove divergence by the limit comparison test, using

$$\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{5}{7m}$$

for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Constants in the
numerator and denominator
generally do not affect
the convergence or divergence
(as long as the term they
are added to
gets large).

So
$\sum \frac{5}{7m+28}
$
will converge or diverge
the same as
$\sum \frac{1}{m}
$.

In this case,
it diverges.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use this as a general rule of thumb in the future.

Comment: As long as you can prove your result if some pedantic professor persists in your presenting a proof.